# How do I append data to a many-to-many field using Ajax?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to update user fields using ajax. I created an APIView for user model using rest-framework. User model includes a many-to-many field named "favorite_entries", with the code below I need to get all the field data beforehand in JS and append new data and call a put request, which seems wrong to me.

**views.py:**

```
class CurrentAuthorView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, )
    http_method_names = ['get', 'put']

    def put(self, request):
        serializer = AuthorSerializer(request.user, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def get(self, request):
        serializer = AuthorSerializer(request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**javascript:**

```
$("#favorite_entry-btn").on("click", function () {
    let entry_id = $(this).attr("data-entry-id");

    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/v1/author/',
        type: 'PUT',
        data: "favorite_entries=3",
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });

});
```

I expect the entry with primary key "3" appended to the field, but it erases all the previous data.

Answer (score 0):

The data property should be a Javascript object in key:value format.

```
$("#favorite_entry-btn").on("click", function () {
    let entry_id = $(this).attr("data-entry-id");

    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/v1/author/',
        type: 'PUT',
        data: { favorite_entries: 3},
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });

});
```